# 'Controlar' en lenguaje formal

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones, coloquialismos

En el Metro de Madrid, así como en otros lugares en España, aconsejan al usuario por megafonía que "*Controle* sus pertenencias en todo momento, por su seguridad."

Me da la impresión de que *Controlar*, en el sentido de *Vigilar*, es una palabra más bien coloquial y que esta fuera de lugar en un contexto formal, como es el caso. Sin embargo, nunca he oido a nadie más expresar esta opinión.

¿Podría alguien con cierto dominio aclarar si estoy en lo cierto o no?

Gracias.

Comment: "Controlar" en el sentido de "ejercer el control" o "mantener bajo control" no está tan desencaminado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno cuando dices Controlar, no es solo Vigilar, porque vigilar es estar atento para que no pase nada. 
El controlar sería verificar que tus pertenencias sigan siendo las mismas. Osea sabes que pertenencias tienes, y verificas que sigas teniendo las mismas **sin cambios**.

Vigilar sería ir mirando que nadie se acerque y te haga nada. Es una medida preventiva.

Y controlar en este caso incluye Vigilar (medida preventiva), pero además es revisar que en un momento de distracción nada haya cambiado (que es una medida no para prevenir, pero de ser posible corregir, o hacer algo como denunciar el robo)

Por ejemplo el control de inventario, es revisar que el inventario sea igual que lo que dicen los papeles (la lista de inventario).

Espero que esto te sirva.

Comment: Parece razonable. Me chirría, la verdad, pero ya que el diccionario lo corrobora...